# import R package without product package name

Tags: android, qt

project: qt5.10/android/qml

I need to use the icon from the resources - R. drawable.icon

Code below is successfully built. But it uses the name of the application package.

```
import myapp.foobar.com.R;
...
.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
```

I would like to import an R package without being bound to the application package name. Is that possible?

---

Or maybe there is a way to access resources without importing the R package?

Or import R-package by specifying the name of the main package indirectly? something like this: `import auto.R`

Answer (score 0):

No, its not possible...R will always consist of Package name with starting